# Disabling function keys based on current app and enabling F1 - F12

Tags: mac, macos, keybindings

I'm not sure if this functionality is built into macOS or if there is an app I must download, please let me know.

I'd like the functionality of the F1-12 buttons to only work as 'function' keys and not, for example, volume-up or volume-down, unless a specific application is open.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Not in sierra yes for el captain using karabiner.  Karabiner elements is still in beta.

Comment: Thanks - as you say not working with Sierra yet but will keep an eye on it.